# How to vectorize to speed up Dataframe apply pandas

Tags: pandas, performance, numpy, optimization, vectorization

I have a tXn (5000 X 100) dataframe wts_df,

```
wts_df.tail().iloc[:, 0:6]
Out[71]: 
                  B         C         H         L         R         T  
2020-09-25  0.038746  0.033689 -0.047835 -0.002641  0.009501 -0.030689   
2020-09-28  0.038483  0.033189 -0.061742  0.001199  0.009490 -0.028370   
2020-09-29  0.038620  0.034957 -0.031341  0.006179  0.007815 -0.027317   
2020-09-30  0.038610  0.034902 -0.014271  0.004512  0.007836 -0.024672   
2020-10-01  0.038790  0.029937 -0.044198 -0.008415  0.008347 -0.030980
```

and two similar txn dataframes, vol_df and rx_df (same index and columns). For now we can use,

```
rx_df = wts_df.applymap(lambda x: np.random.rand())
vol_df = wts_df.applymap(lambda x: np.random.rand())
```

I need to do this (simplified):

```
for date in wts_df.index:
  wts = wts_df.loc[date]   # is a vector now 1Xn

  # mutliply all entries of rx_df and vol_df until this date by these wts, and sum across columns

  rx = rx_df.truncate(after=date)   # still a dataframe but truncated at a given date, kXn
  vol = vol_df_df.truncate(after=date)   

  wtd_rx = (wts * rx).sum(1)   # so a vector kX1
  wtd_vol = (wts * vol).sum(1)   

  # take ratio
  rx_vol = rx / vol

  rate[date] = rx_vol.tail(20).std()
```

So rate looks like this

```
pd.Series(rate).tail()
Out[71]: 
              rate         
2020-09-25  0.0546   
2020-09-28  0.0383  
2020-09-29  0.0920    
2020-09-30  0.0510  
2020-10-01  0.0890
```

The above loop is slow, so i tried this:

```
def rate_calc(wts, date, rx_df=rx_df, vol_df=vol_df):
    wtd_rx = (rx_df * wts).sum(1) 
    wtd_vol = (vol_df * wts).sum(1)
    rx_vol = wtd_rx / wtd_vol
    rate = rx_vol.truncate(after=date).tail(20).std() 
    return rate

rates = wts_df.apply(lambda x: rate_calc(x, x.name), axis=1)
```

This is still very slow. Moreover I need to do this for multiple wts_df contained in a dict so the total operations takes a lot time.

```
rates = {key: val.apply(lambda x: rate_calc(x, x.name), axis=1) for key, val in wts_df_dict.iteritems()}
```

Any ideas how to speed such operations?

Comment: Thanks for sharing your input. Can you kindly share your expected output in the question? Also, you have two input dataframes that are not in the question, so it will be challenging for anyone to answer.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question, because questions with working code, which are seeking guidance to improve performance, are better suited for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Your question falls under the category of 'optimization' so allow me to share with you few pointers to solve your problem.

First, when it comes to speed, always use %timeit to ensure you get better results with a new stratgegy.

Second, there are few ways to iterate a data:

1. with `iterrows()` -- use it only when the data sample is small (or better yet, try not to use it as it's too slow).
2. With `apply` --better alternative to iterrows and much more efficient but when the data set is large (like in your example) it may present a delay problem.
3. `Vectorizing` --simply put, you execute the operation on the entire column/array and its significantly fast. **Winner!**

So, in order to solve your speed problem your strategy should be in the form of **vectorizing**. So here's how it should work; (mind the **.values**):

`df['new_column'] = my_function(df['column_1'].values, df['column_2'].values...)` and you will note a super fast result.

Comment: Thanks, that's the exact reason i tagged my question with vectorization. Now added optimization also. But the question is how to vectorize in this case. It does not seem that straightforward.

Comment: @dayum Don’t try to do my_function with your business logic presented in your for loop. Start with a simple dummy result and work it up to your need (the entire business logic). Also, since we don’t have your data it’s very hard to get the right result with vectorization